# Why is it easier to observe B-meson oscillations than D-meson ones?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-detectors, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

B-meson oscillations were observed several years ago by the CDF experiment [B-oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E2%80%93Bbar_oscillation), but D-meson could not be observed until very recently [by the LHCb experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1230). I'm wondering why is it more difficult to observe D-oscillations than B-oscillations, taking into account that $D^0$ mesons have lower mass than $B^0$ ones.

Comment: The mass of the c quark (~1GeV) and that of the b quark (~4Gev) are  large , in the same order of magnitude with respect to the lighter s quark (~0.1GeV). Though charm mesons were found in the accelerators with lower energies, the high energies available at LHC made possible to study D oscillations in one experiment, afaik. There were data fitted with oscillations in the lower energy accelerators, but not to give definitive answers.

Comment: it is just a comment. Reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E2%80%93Bbar_oscillation I think that nobody proposed or built a special D factory experiment, and that is why D oscillations were not verified before B. Somebody involved in these experiments would be to ask your question.

Comment: One added complexity is D mesons lifetime. It is very small compared to Kaon and B meson because D meson can decay within the generation, while B meson and Kaon decays have to cross generations. With such a small lifetime it will be difficult to measure oscillations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the oscillation probability (for K, B, D mesons) is proportional to the mass difference of mass eigenstate. This mass difference is related to the oscillation diagrams like [image: this]

To compute the amplitude of these diagrams you have to consider the CKM matrix for decays between quark families.
if you consider all the diagrams you will see that in D meson this is strongly suppressed wrt K and B since it is proportional to  (Vcb Vub)^2 . So the  oscillation is slower and more difficult to observe